# Shiny:How to identify which SelectInput() is being selected and using that information in server.r

Tags: r, shiny

I am quite new to the ways of shiny , so forgive me if this is not possible or something obvious.
I am basically trying to identify which select Input is being selected and , and pass the information into my server.r. How will I go about doing this ?

My logic of the app looks like this :

ui.R

```
 selectInput("A","Select a class",choices =levels(class)), selectInput("B","Select a Sub Class",choices=levels(Sub_class))
```

server .r

```
if ("A" is selected ,then do something with "A" )else if("B" is selected , do something else
```

The actions performed in the if conditions are mutually exclusive , performed are mutually exclusive

Thanks a lot !

Comment: If the actions performed are truly mutually exclusive, is B really a sub class of A?

Comment: first argument of selectInput is the id. So if you call `input$A` on server side it will automatically trigger the reactive environment within you trigger it. No need for `if()` statements,...

Comment: @Benjamin , its a typo , B should read Class as well

Comment: @BigDataScientist , Thanks .So , I can say for eg :` -p1<-RenderPlot ("A") , p2<-RenderPlot("B")` , and if user selected "A" , my ui will only dispaly p1 eventhoigh 
 I have plotouput("p1") & plotouput("p2") ?

Comment: no that code will not work. Maybe a few tutorials would be a good start,...

Comment: @BigDataScientist Hi edited the above , I understand the syntax is not correct , but is my logic ? i.e can I render multiple plots in server and display only the selected ones wrt user input , without any other additional constraints , I have been reading about "Conditional Panel " , I am not sure if thats is what I should look into

Comment: You might be better of passing a list to the select input. This will put all of the options in one box, but allow only one to be selected. The argument would look like `choices = list (A = c ("a1", "a2"), B = c ("b1", "b2", "b3"))`

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks Benjamin , however my choices for A and B are large , I wont be able to display all in one box

Comment: , My quiestion really boils down to know , which selectInput is being slected using their id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server, you can select your inputs as input$inputId. In your case, it would be:

`input$A` and `input$B`.

Something like:

```
server <- function(input, output){
    // Do something
    // Use A
    input$A
    // Use B
    input$B
}
```

If they are mutually exclusive, I don't think you should use two different selectInputs for them, instead use something like a radio button where the user can select only one of them at once.

Comment: Thanks , but "A" and "B" have are factor variables with different levels ,so radio button will be tricky .

Comment: Hi , didnt realise at the time but this worked , I created a radio button which initially  has Class A , Class B and depending on which is selected , I changed my selectinput()  and do the required action .Thanks!